# Initialize databases in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

In my ASP.NET Core app, I use quite a few Azure services e.g. Table Storage, DocumentDb, etc. As part of the initialization routine, I need to make sure these databases exist and if not, I need to create them.

Currently, I handle this initialization in Configure method in Startup.cs using the code below.

```
// Initialize databases
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices
          .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
          .CreateScope())
          {
            var blobClient = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyBlobStorageClient>();
            var dbClient = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDocumentDbClient>();
            var tsClient = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyTableStorage.TableStorageClient>();
            MyInitializer(blobClient, dbClient, tsClient).Wait();
           }
```

Is this where I should handle my initializations?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you could leverage your code to initialize your Azure Services. Also, you could add a singleton service of your StorageClient/DocumentDbClient and check whether your service is exist and create the specific resource if not exists before you do CURD operations to your Azure Services. Here is the code snippet for my `AzureBlobStorageClient`, you could refer to it.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<AzureStorageConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureStorageConfig"));
    services.AddSingleton<AzureBlobStorageClient>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
"AzureStorageConfig": {
  "AccountName": "<your-storage-account-name>",
  "AccountKey": "<your-storage-account-key>"
}
```

**AzureBlobStorageClient.cs**

```
public class AzureBlobStorageClient
{
    private CloudBlobClient _cloudBlobClient;
    public AzureBlobStorageClient(IOptions<AzureStorageConfig> config)
    {
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(config.Value.AccountName, config.Value.AccountKey), true);
        _cloudBlobClient=storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    }

    public async Task<bool> EnsureContainer(string containerName)
    {
        var storageContainer = _cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        return await storageContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
    }
}

public class AzureStorageConfig
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string AccountKey { get; set; }
}
```

**AzureStorageController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class AzureStorageController : Controller
{
    private AzureBlobStorageClient _storageClient;
    public ValuesController(AzureBlobStorageClient storageClient)
    {
        _storageClient = storageClient;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {   
        //_storageClient.EnsureContainer("<blob-container-name>");
        return await Task.FromResult("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with the CreateIfNotExists approach is that it should not be necessary to check the containers etc. exist on every request. Unless it is normal for containers to be deleted while the app is running of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use our recently release .Net Core SDK: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-sdk-dotnet-core

Also, this page has some key performance tips for the SDKs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-performance-tips#sdk-usage